# Read CDATA section based on where clause using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, cdata

I am trying to read CDATA section of an xml node based upon the where clause.

```
<Book>
  <BookItem ISBN="SKS84747"><![CDATA[20]]> </BookItem>
  <BookItem ISBN="LHKGOI84747"><![CDATA[50]]> </BookItem>
  <BookItem ISBN="PUOT84747"><![CDATA[20]]> </BookItem>
</Book>
```

This code gives me all the CDATA sections,

```
var value = from v in x.Descendants("BookItem").OfType<XCData>()
                                select (string)v.Value;
```

How to put where clause based on ISBN ?
How can I read this CDATA using LINQ to XML.

Comment: HashItem is a Typo for BookItem, or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value = x.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>()
                .Where(m => m.Parent.Name == "BookItem" && m.Parent.Attribute("ISBN").Value == "PUOT84747")
                .ToList();
```

or

before ToList()

```
.Select(cdata => cdata.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = Resource1.String1;
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var isbn = "SKS84747";
var query = string.Format("BookItem[@ISBN='{0}']", isbn);
var book = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement(query);

if (book != null)
    Console.WriteLine(book.Value);
```

OR

```
var book =
    doc.Root.Descendants("BookItem").Where(
        x => x.Attribute("ISBN") != null && x.Attribute("ISBN").Value == isbn).Select(x => x.Value).
        FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
var book = (from item in doc.Root.Descendants("BookItem")
            where item.Attributes("ISBN").Any() && item.Attribute("ISBN").Value == isbn
            select item.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```